# Detecting line's intersections

Tags: java, arrays, processing, trigonometry, intersection

I am trying to solve this problem: drawing random lines on the screen then create dots at intersection of all the lines. My solution: instead of creating real lines, I use little dots to construct lines. Each "line" is an instance of a class called Pointe.  I store all the coordinates of each line instance in it's own array. In order to detect intersection, I wrote function collide() to compare each line's stored coordinates. If the distance <10, I change the line's thickness to 10 pixel to create the "balloon" effect.

```
int p = 0;
class Pointe {
  int x;
  int y;
  int speedX;
  int speedY;
  float size = 2;
  color c = color(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  int position_stored[] = {};
  Pointe(int xPosition, int yPosition, int speed_X, int speed_Y) {
    x = xPosition;
    y= yPosition;
    speedX = int(random(speed_X));
    speedY = int(random(speed_Y));
  }

  int b = int(mouseX);
  int n = int(mouseY);

  void move() {
    x = x + speedX;
    y = y + speedY;
    if (x>60) {x = x; y = y;}
    if (y>60) {y = y; x = x;}
    store_position();
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    ellipse(x,y,size,size);
  }
  int getX() {return x;}
  int getY() {return y;}
  void store_position() {
    int position_stored2[] = append(position_stored,getX());
    int position_stored3[] = append(position_stored2,getY());
    position_stored = position_stored3;
  }

  void collide(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length ; i=i+2) {
        int distance = int(dist(x,y,a[i-1],a[i])); 
        if (distance < 20) {size = 10;}
        else {size = 2;}
    }
  }
}
int number = 109;
void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i <number; i++) {
    points[i] = new Pointe(int(random(600)),int(random(600)),int(random(-6,6)),int(random(-6,6)));
  }
}

Pointe[] points =  new Pointe[number];

void draw(){
  for (int i = 0; i <number; i++) {
    for (int z = 0; z <number; z++) {
      if (i == z) {}
      points[i].collide(points[z].position_stored);
    }
    points[i].display();
    points[i].move();   
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *"My solution: instead of creating real lines, I use little dots to construct lines"* - this does not really sound like a solution, but rather like a source of new problems. Any particular reason *why* you are doing it this way?

Comment: Clarifications should not be added as an answer, but by by adding a comment or editing the original question. (And asking the same question again in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771887 will not help here either). Obviously, the question or your intention are not clear enough.

Comment: Hi Marco, I use points because I would like to create scribbles later on (not just lines).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple math problem. What you have for every line are 2 points in the plane, you can get the line equation using those 2 points follow this https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/algebra1-brushup/graph-eqns-brushups/v/equation-of-a-line-3
Ones you have the equation of 2 different lines you can find the points where they intersect by G(x) = F(x).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the possibility to use Processing Script here at the moment. Processing is rather similar to Java, and with minor changes, such a script can be ran as a Java Applet.

However, your approach is questionable in many ways.

The first call in the `draw` method should actually be

```
void draw()
{
    background(0xFFFFFF);
    ...
}
```

in order to clear the background. If you are not doing this, then anything that you see will be unrelated to the "state" that you actually have.

Currently, you are storing the coordinates of the points (after their movement) in the `position_stored` array. But the contents of this array is not used for painting, but only for the distance computations!

Most importantly: How long should this animation run? The longer it runs, the more memory you will need. You are always storing new point coordinates...

So in the end, everybody can - in the best case - only **guess** what you want to achieve. And I **guess** it is something like this, but considering my limited knowledge about Processing, and the intention to keep at least a *slight* similarity to what you originally posted, this is still **poorly** implemented and should probably be solved differently.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ScribblingTest extends PApplet
{
    class Pointe
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int speedX;
        int speedY;
        float size = 2;
        int c = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));

        Pointe(int xPosition, int yPosition, int speed_X, int speed_Y)
        {
            x = xPosition;
            y = yPosition;
            speedX = (int)(random(speed_X));
            speedY = (int)(random(speed_Y));
        }

        Pointe(Pointe other)
        {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            speedX = other.speedX;
            speedY = other.speedY;
            c = other.c;
        }


        void move()
        {
            x = x + speedX;
            y = y + speedY;
            if (x > 600)
            {
                x = 0;
            }
            if (y > 600)
            {
                y = 0;
            }
            if (x < 0)
            {
                x = 600;
            }
            if (y < 0)
            {
                y = 600;
            }
        }

        void display()
        {
            noStroke();
            fill(c);
            ellipse(x, y, size, size);
        }

        int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }

        int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }

        boolean collide(int[] a)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i = i + 2)
            {
                int distance = (int)(dist(x, y, a[i - 1], a[i]));
                if (distance < 20)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    int number = 20;
    int maxSteps = 300;
    int currentStep = 0;
    Pointe[][] points = new Pointe[number][maxSteps];

    public void setup()
    {
        size(600, 600);
        background(255);
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new Pointe[maxSteps];
            points[i][0] = new Pointe(
                (int)(random(600)), 
                (int)(random(600)), 
                (int)(random(-6, 6)), 
                (int)(random(-6, 6)));
        }
    }


    public void draw()
    {
        background(0xFFFFFF);

        int currentIndex = currentStep % maxSteps;
        int nextIndex = (currentStep + 1) % maxSteps;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            Pointe currentP = points[i][currentIndex];
            Pointe nextP = new Pointe(currentP);
            nextP.move();

            boolean collides = false;
            for (int j=0; j<number; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    for (int k=0; k<maxSteps; k++)
                    {
                        Pointe otherP = points[j][k];
                        if (otherP != null)
                        {
                            float d = dist(nextP.x, nextP.y, otherP.x, otherP.y);
                            if (d < 20)
                            {
                                collides = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (collides)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (collides)
            {
                nextP.size = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                nextP.size = 2;
            }

            points[i][nextIndex] = nextP;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<maxSteps; j++)
            {
                Pointe p = points[i][j];
                if (p != null)
                {
                    p.display();
                }
            }
        }
        currentStep++;


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time working this out for me.
I actually don't have java now so I can't test your program. But I don't want to clear background because I want the dots to draw on the screen, like when you are scribbling on a white board without erasing it. I will test this java applet and let you know.

Comment: There should only be few modifictions necessary to convert it back into a Processing script (e.g. `(int)` has to be converted to `int`, really just small things). I see your intention with *not* clearing the background, but for example, when you resize your window, everything that you painted before will be lost anyhow...